# Terraform unable to pass in list as a variable in bash Linux

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform

As part of my CI/CD pipeline, I am running terraform and attempting to pass in a local variable. Unfortunately, the variable name is just taken literally.

I have tried changing the quotes around but this does not seem to do anything.

I am on Linux Ubuntu and version 0.11.14 of terraform

The bash code is

```
azip=1.1.1.1
```

Calling the plan command by:

```
terraform plan  -var 'ip_azure=["$azip2"]'
```

The following plan is displayed:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + aws_route53_record.dns_azure
      id:                <computed>
      allow_overwrite:   <computed>
      fqdn:              <computed>
      name:              "dns_azure"
      records.#:         "1"
      records.767631455: "$azip2"
      ttl:               "60"
      type:              "A"
      zone_id:           "Z2X9DFDU4LXXC6"


Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

I would expect

```
records.767631455: "1.1.1.1"
```

Whenever I put the ip address directly into the plan e.g.

```
terraform plan  -var 'ip_azure=["1.1.1.1"]'
```

I get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@bellackn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482759/bellackn) for giving me the correct direction

I ran the following

```
terraform plan  -var "ip_azure=[\"${azip2}\"]"
```

and it worked. Looks like I need to escape the double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Variables between single quotes don't get evaluated in Bash. If you use...

```
terraform plan  -var "ip_azure=[${azip2}]"
```

... instead, it should work. Probably you don't even need the `{}` in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just tried that but I get the following' terraform plan  -var "ip_azure=[${azip2}]"'
Usage: terraform plan [options] [DIR-OR-PLAN]

  Generates an execution plan for Terraform.

  This execution plan can be reviewed prior to running apply to get a
  sense for what Terraform will do. Optionally, the plan can be saved to
  a Terraform plan file, and apply can take this plan file to execute
  this plan exactly.

  If a saved plan is passed as an argument, this command will output
  the saved plan co.....

Comment: If I see correctly, there still is a single quote at the end of your command. Please remove it and try again.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer above. It seemed to do the trick. Appreciate your guidance.